# Remove left padding from a list (CSS)

Tags: html, list, css

According to chrome's "inspect element" there's a `padding-left:40px` coming from "user agent stylesheet". I would like to avoid this without ignoring the user agent stylesheet for the rest of my web.

code: http://jsfiddle.net/FranLegon/kvhu2vg4/
img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMvKC.png

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>li {list-style-type:none; padding:0; margin:0;} </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>aaaaa</li>
            <li>bbbbb</li>
            <li>ccccc</li>
            <li>ddddd</li>
            <li>eeeee</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Try doing `padding-left` instead of just `padding` or adding it to the `ul` and not the `li`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get list to center when using UL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891011/cant-get-list-to-center-when-using-ul)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default padding is on the `ul` element - not the `li` elements.

```
ul { padding-left: 0; }
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/4L0fnb98/)

In most browsers, the `ul` has a default `padding-left` value of `40px`.

```css
ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>aaaaa</li>
  <li>bbbbb</li>
  <li>ccccc</li>
  <li>ddddd</li>
  <li>eeeee</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: "default padding is on the ul element " +1; visual example of where the padding is: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbdojY

Answer (score 1):

You should not only apply it to the list-items, but also to the list:

```css
ul, li {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>aaaaa</li>
    <li>bbbbb</li>
    <li>ccccc</li>
    <li>ddddd</li>
    <li>eeeee</li>
</ul>
```